# dplyr filter multiple variables (columns) with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I plan to filter data for multiple columns with multiple columns in one line to reduce the time used for running the code. This is sample data that I used to test my code. Basically, I want to remove any rows containing 0, 1, 2, and NA.

```
test <- data.frame(A = c(1,0,2,3,4,0,5,6,0,7,0,8,0,9,NA),
                 B = c(0,1,0,2,3,4,0,5,0,7,8,0,NA,9,0),
                 C = c(1,2,3,0,0,4,5,6,0,7,0,8,NA,0,9))
```

I used the following code to clean my data. Although it does the job, the code is very tedious and takes me quite a while when I run it with a large database.

```
test %>%  filter(!is.na(A)) %>%
filter(!is.na(B)) %>%
filter(!is.na(C)) %>% 
filter(A != 0) %>% 
filter(A != 1) %>%
filter(A != 2) %>% 
filter(B != 0) %>% 
filter(B != 1) %>%
filter(B != 2) %>%
filter(C != 0) %>% 
filter(C != 1) %>%
filter(C != 2)

  A B C
1 6 5 6
2 7 7 7
```

I tried to shorten the code using `filter`, `filter_at`, and `any_vars`, but it did not work. Below are my attempts to deal with this problem (all of these codes did not work because they could not delete the row containing 0 (or 1,2, and NA).

```
df_total <- test %>%
filter_at(vars(A, B, C), any_vars(!is.na(.))) %>%
filter_at(vars(A, B, C), any_vars(. != 2)) %>%
filter_at(vars(A, B, C), any_vars(. != 1)) %>%
filter_at(vars(A, B, C), any_vars(. != 0))

df_total <- test %>%
filter_at(vars(A, B, C), any_vars(!is.na(.) | . != 2 | . != 1 | . != 0))

df_total <- test %>%
filter(!is.na(A) | A!= 2 | A!= 1 | A!= 0) %>%
filter(!is.na(B) | B!= 2 | B!= 1 | B!= 0) %>%
filter(!is.na(C) | C!= 2 | C!= 1 | C!= 0) %>%
```

I cannot figure out what I did incorrectly here. I went back and forth between the documentation and R to solve this problem, but my efforts were useless. Could you please suggest to me what I did wrong in my code? How can I write a code for multiple columns with multiple conditions in just one line? The point for one line is to speed up the running time for R. Any advice/ suggestions/ resources to find the answer would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(.) & if_all(everything(), ~ !(.x %in% 0:2)))

#>   A B C
#> 1 6 5 6
#> 2 7 7 7
```

Comment: Hi PaulS, thank you for your answer. Could I ask for clarification? I have more than A, B, and C in my database. In fact, I have almost 400 variables, and I would like to filter based on only these three columns. I do not think _everything()_ is not appropriate in this case. How should I adjust your code to accommodate this problem?

Comment: @Kob: I guess the following will work: `test %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(.[c("A", "B", "C")]) & if_all(c(A, B, C), ~ !(.x %in% 0:2)))`

Comment: It works perfectly. May I ask for the implication of some point in this code, please? My first question is, why did you put **.** after _complete.cases_? And another question is, why did you use if_all instead of if_any? My understanding is that if_all will yield the intersection between sets. In other words, the row will be deleted if these three columns contain 0 (or 1 and 2). Clearly, my understanding is incorrect. Can you enlighten me about this?

Comment: @Kob: Q1: the . means the output coming from the previous pipe (dataframe `test`, in this case). Q2: with the following `filter(A != 0) %>% 
filter(A != 1) %>%
filter(A != 2)`, you mean deleting all rows that contain 0 or 1 or 2. Hence, one can translate that to `filter(!A %in% 0:2)`. Since one has to have this condition satisfied also for columns `B` and `C`, then one needs an `and`: `filter((!A %in% 0:2) & (!B %in% 0:2) & (!C %in% 0:2))`

Comment: This is what I was looking for the whole day yesterday. Thank you so much for your clarification!!! It is super (super) helpful to understand the function for a newbie like me. I appreciate your time explaining all of this.

Answer (score 2):

```
test %>% 
    filter(across(c(A, B, C), function(x) !is.na(x) & !x %in% c(0, 1, 2)))

# A B C
# 6 5 6
# 7 7 7
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Adromine. Correct me if I am wrong. *across* function is depreciated in the current version of dplyr, and it is suggested that we should change to if_any or if_all, right? I ran the code successfully with across function, and then I decided to change because of this depreciation. I tried to use if_any in my code, but it did not work.

Comment: `across` isn't deprecated. The `_at`, `_all` variants of mutate, summarise, etc were deprecated. `if_any` and `if_all` are currently recommended versions as well, but they are only applicable for use within `filter`. You can replace the across with `if_all` in the above code. You can read more about `across` and `if_any/all` on their [help page](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html).

Comment: I think I totally misunderstood about the depreciation of these functions. Thank you so much for the clarification. I have read this help page before, but I still have a doubt about `if_any/all`. To my understanding, `if_all` will yield an interaction of sets and a union of sets for `if_any`. In my case, I want any row containing 0 (or 1 and 2) to be deleted from any columns of A, B, and C. That's why I chose to use `if_any` rather than `if_all`. But it did not work as I thought. Did I misunderstand something here? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: `filter(if_all(cols = c(A, B, C), .fns = fun1))` is equivalent to `filter(fun1(A) & fun(B) & fun(C))` while `filter(if_any(cols = c(A, B, C), .fns = fun1))` is same as `filter(fun1(A) | fun(B) | fun(C))`